# Syntax Error while trying to update a database

Tags: mysql

I am having a syntax error for an update.

c) Update InstructorLoc for Instructor 111 to DA 206

Comment: MySQL's  BNF (Backus–Naur form) UPDATE syntax follows `UPDATE <table> SET <column> = <value>[, ...] WHERE <column> = <value>`  see documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: A syntax error? Looks more like a homework instruction.

Answer (score -1):

`UPDATE InstroctorLoc SET DA = 206 WHERE Instructor = 111;`